# How to create jar file that only includes properties files using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

I want to create a jar file in eclipse and i want to add only properties file in jar file. How to do it? 
I have a project that have only properties files(not a single java file in project).

Comment: In eclipse go on the project, open the context menu and choose "Export". You can select JAR-files as target.

Comment: This is not working because my project have only .Properties files.

Comment: If it is not a Java project, you can use the _Archive File_ export wizard (a JAR file is a ZIP file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below navigation

`Project Explorer/Package Explorer -> Right click on the project -> Export -> Jar File -> A 'JAR File Specification' pop-up comes up`.

You project is by default checked. Expand your project structure and select the `src` second and in the right side, content of `src` will be shown. Select all the files(properties in your case), and click on finish

Comment: My project is not appear where by default projects selected

Comment: Then your project is not  of type `Java Project`. You have to use `jar` command to generate jar file